# Change attribute value in nested classes

Tags: python, class, nested, attributes

I'm facing a little problem that I can't solve. I have an upper class containing as an attribute a list of objects from a lower class. I want to modify an attribute of the objects of the lower class, from a function of the upper class.

Here's my code:

```
class Leaf:
    def __init__(self, size = None, color = None):
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.leafs = []
        self.leafs.append(Leaf(size=1))
        self.leafs.append(Leaf(size=2))
        
    def change_color(self):
        self.leafs[0].color = 'blue'
        self.leafs[1].color = 'green'

oak = Tree()
print(oak.leafs[0].color)
```

I would like the `print(oak.leafs[0].color)` to display 'blue', but it displays 'None'.
Would you guys know how to solve this?

Comment: `oak.change_color()`?

Answer (score 3):

You never call the  function that changes the color:

```
oak = Tree()
oak.change_color()  #  <- !!
print(oak.leafs[0].color)
# blue
```